# Password manager preventing OnBlur from triggering

Tags: html, angular, user-interface, dom-events, web-frontend

I use 1Password as my password manager, and have the extension for it in Chrome. I noticed an issue on my site where when I tab out of any input field, the `OnBlur` event does not trigger. The event still triggers if I click out of the field, only when I tab out does it not trigger. When I disable the password manager from autofilling credentials, then my `OnBlur` triggers as expected.

This is the setting in 1Password I disabled to make my `OnBlur` work again.[image]

Any ideas on how to get around this?

My frontend is in Angular, and the only work around I have been able to come up with so far is to listen for both the `blur` event, and the `tab`/`shift + tab` event to trigger the blur function. I don't like this as lots of the time this will cause the `onBlur` to trigger twice for anyone that isn't using this password manager.

```html
<input #input
    (focus)="onFocus()"
    (keydown.tab)="onBlur()"
    (keydown.shift.tab)="onBlur()"
    (blur)="onBlur()">
```

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about it. When the page load, 1pass hooks into the input field, which means they modify the input.
So if you want to prevent it, you need to know what 1pass does under the hood and make your app and 1pass compatible, this process is time consuming as 1pass doesn't public their API which means your changes, if any, will stop working at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `autocomplete` and check if it works or not and for the part where you are using this password manager, most of the people don't use this specific password manager. So, that should not be a big problem at all.

Comment: Disabling `autocomplete` does not seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Well, what I am guessing now is that your password manager forcefully enable the `autocomplete` attribute.